# When does uniqueness of a stable equilibrium imply it is globally stable?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, gradient-flows

Given a gradient dynamical system

$$\dot x=-\nabla f(x),$$

my question is:

(1) If there exists only one equilibrium $x^*$ which is stable (if necessary, this can be changed to *stable asymptotically stable*), can we conclude that $x^*$ is **globally asymptotically stable**, i.e. **the whole phase space** is the basin of attraction of $x^*$?

(2) If there exists many equilibria, but only one of them $x^*$ is stable (if necessary, this can be changed to *stable asymptotically stable*), can we conclude that $x^*$ is **almost globally asymptotically stable**, i.e. **the whole phase space except for a set of measure zero** is the basin of attraction of $x^*$?

This question is related to [Mathoverflow: Global stability for dynamical systems in $R^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25162/global-stability-for-dynamical-systems-in-rn), but my question is in the context of *being a gradient system*.

Comment: Just to clarify: I assume you mean there's a unique equilibrium, and that equilibrium is stable? (Otherwise, if you mean there's a unique stable equilibrium, but also allow the existence of unstable equilibria, there are simple counterexamples, e.g. $f(x) = x^3 - x$.)

Comment: @MartinM.W. Ah yes, true! I actually assume there can exist many equilibria, but only one of them is stable. Thus I will add 'almost' globally asymptotically stable in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a smooth counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$: a function $f$ whose gradient flow has a unique equilibrium, which is also stable, but whose basin of attraction is not the entire plane. It's easiest to describe $f$ via a diagram of its level curves:

[image]

The shaded area is the basin of attraction of the equilibrium. For clarity I've labeled the values of some of the level curves. For instance, on the central area, the function looks something like $2^y \cos x$ restricted to $ [-\pi/2, \pi/2] \times \mathbb{R}$. It should be clear that you can smoothly patch together $C^\infty$ functions to match the diagram.

Conceptually: the $y$-axis forms a ridge that dynamically separates the two halves of the plane. Since $f$ is increasing on the $y$-axis, the gradient is nonzero. On one side of the ridge we can arrange for $f$ to have a single local minimum; on the other, we can let $f$ just decrease as $x$ increases. (All this assumes we're interested in smooth functions; it's not clear to me what happens in the real analytic category.)

Comment: I am pretty sure setting $f = f_M + f_B$ with \begin{gather}
f_M(x,y) = \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} + 1\right)\left( \frac{1}{1+ y^2} \right)\\
f_B(x,y) = - \exp( - x^2 - (y-y_0)^2) 
\end{gather}
would give an example in the analytic category if $y_0$ is chosen positive and sufficiently large.